# Nebular Oauth2 google login not redirect

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular, ngx-admin

i'm using nebular oauth2 google login like this

in my auth.module.ts

```
NbAuthModule.forRoot({
  strategies: [
    NbOAuth2AuthStrategy.setup({
      name: 'google',
      clientId: '219027435285-822fstg8ddquhag9bcu94v5vutclng42.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      clientSecret: '',
      authorize: {
        endpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
        responseType: NbOAuth2ResponseType.TOKEN,
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        redirectUri: 'https://kewirus-v1.web.app/auth/callback',
      },
    }),
  ],
  forms: {},
}),
```

in my logincomponent

```
  userPass:any;
  userMail:any;
  token:any;
  constructor(service: NbAuthService,@Inject(NB_AUTH_OPTIONS) options: {},cd: ChangeDetectorRef, router: Router) {
    super(service,options,cd, router);
  }

  alive = true;

  login() {
    this.service.authenticate('google')
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
      .subscribe((authResult: NbAuthResult) => {
        console.log();

      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.alive = false;
  }
```

and in my callbackcomponent

```
  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private authService: NbAuthService, private router: Router) {
    this.authService.authenticate('google')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((authResult: NbAuthResult) => {
        if (authResult.isSuccess()) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('../pages/dashboard');
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
```

it should redirect to dashboard page but it redirect back to login not to dashboard page. what did i do wrong?

Comment: Can you check the routing by manually going to that page? Might routing have issue.


please share console data.

Comment: i change ../pages to /pages then it works, but i don't know how to get the user profile

Comment: authResult  will have userData. or try to change the scope: 'basic_info'. It may help you out.

Comment: my current scope like this scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'